# Setting the length property of array in Solidity

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

What does setting the `length` property of an array do. In most other languages `length` is a function that return the length of an arra, but in this code the `length` property is being set.

```
struct ledger_t {
  uint8 WinningNum1;
  uint8 WinningNum2;
  uint8 WinningNum3;
  uint8 WinningNum4;
  bytes32 ClosingHash;
  bytes32 OpeningHash;
  mapping(address=>bet_t) bets;
  uint Guess4OutOf4;
  uint Guess3OutOf4;
  uint Guess2OutOf4;
  uint Guess1OutOf4;
  uint PriceOfTicket;
  uint ExpirationTime; //for eventual refunds only, ~2 weeks after draw announced
}
ledger_t[] public ledger;

//constructor
function TheEthereumLottery() {
  owner = msg.sender;
  ledger.length = 0;
  IndexOfCurrentDraw = 0;
  referral_fee = 90;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `length` property of a Solidity array can be used to get and set the length of that array. To get the length simply read from the property:

`l = ar.length`

and to set a new length for the array simply assign the new length value:

`ar.length = 5`

This is different to most languages that would implement a specific function for getting and setting the length of arrays.